# correctly calling a lilypond scheme function

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I have some general questions regarding calling a scheme function which I will ask using the following example code (which gives no errors and produces an output pdf):

```
\version "2.20.0"

pageSong = 
#(define-scheme-function
   (title music)
   (string? ly:music?)
      #{
        \bookpart { 
          \header {
            title = $title
          } 
          \score {
            $music
            \layout {}
          }
        }
      #})

title = "myTitle"
music = { { c' c' c' c'} \addlyrics { one two three four }}
foo = 1
$(pageSong title music)
```

- If I remove the line `foo = 1`, I will get a compilation error saying `Unbound variable: music`. Why? And why does it not occur when I have that line?
- If I replace `$` by `#`, no error occurs (even if the `foo = 1` line is missing), but no output is created either. Why?
- [This](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/extending/scheme-function-usage) says:

> You call a scheme function from LilyPond by writing its name preceded
> by \, followed by its arguments.

But writing `\pageSong \title \music` or `\pageSong $title $music` or `\pageSong title music` gives the error message `bad expression type` during compilation. So what is the correct syntax that was meant in the linked source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens with the code

```
music = { ... }
$(pageSong title music)
```

is that the LilyPond parser scans the input just after the music expression `{ ... }`, because if there were something like `\addlyrics`, that would affect it. The dollar introduces an expression that is evaluated *immediately* as soon as it is read, as opposed to the hash. So in this case, the Scheme code execution happens too early, before the assignment has completed.

The usual way to insert Scheme code is with the hash, which does not have this effect. But with the hash, the parser has to do more work to recognize expression types because it cannot see the value in advance, so this only works in certain contexts (most of them, but not all of them; I do not actually know if recognizing embedded `\bookpart` blocks would be feasible or not).

Here, all you have to do is to let the bookpart be processed by calling `toplevel-bookpart-handler` yourself on it rather than relying on this being done by the parser.

```
\version "2.22.1"

pageSong =
#(define-void-function (title music) (string? ly:music?)
   (toplevel-bookpart-handler
      #{
        \bookpart {
          \header {
            title = $title
          }
          \score {
            $music
            \layout {}
          }
        }
      #}))

title = "myTitle"
music = { { c' c' c' c'} \addlyrics { one two three four }}
\pageSong \title \music
```

The page https://extending-lilypond.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lily-and-scheme.html#hash-vs-dollar has some amount of information.